# Passar TempData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Boa Tarde pessoal estou com o seguinte problema, preciso passar uma variável para outro controller e estou tentando fazer isso por TempData, segue o código:

```
var user = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var getUser = db.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(user));
var userName = getUser.Nome;
TempData["UsuarioTemp"] = UsuarioTemp;
```

Este código acima se encontra no HomeController, e quero chamar esta TempData no XmlController que seria essa:

```
 HomeController ArquivoX = new HomeController();
 var NomeUsuario = ArquivoX.TempData["UsuarioTemp"];
```

O problema é que toda vez q executo este metodo e TempData volta como Null, e não sei como resolver.
Se alguem puder ajudar eu agradeço.

Comment: Já tentou sem o `ArquivoX.`?

Comment: Sim, mas dai não consigo por o TempData, ele diz que não contém no contexto atual.

Comment: Tem alguma coisa errada em outro lugar, porque este é um objeto global. Preciso sair, se ninguém resolver eu vejo melhor, mas acho que precisará de mais informações do seu código.

Comment: ok vlw, vou dar uma revisada melhor aqui.

Comment: Que tal usar [Session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httpcontext.session(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Então acontece que o código aqui foi feito de tal maneira que não consigo usar a biblioteca System.Web.Mvc, eu teria que fazer de alguma forma que não utiliza-se TempData, Session, ViewBag, Etc.

Comment: É um projeto ASP.NET MVC que você não consegue usar a biblioteca `System.Web.Mvc`? Me parece bem planejado.

Comment: Você deve deixar claro isso na pergunta, para evitar respostas desnecessárias para o seu contexto.

Comment: Agora comecei entender o problema, tá enroscado.

Comment: É então, sera que se eu usar variável global resolveria o problema?

Comment: Pessoal consegui resolver, criei uma variável global static e resolveu meu problema, mesmo assim obrigado pela atenção de todos :D

Comment: Olá, [neste artido do Eduardo Píres](http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2013/06/asp-net-mvc-viewdata-viewbag-tempdata/) você poderá compreender melhor como utilizar o TempData.

Answer (score 3):

Após utilizar o valor da variavel `TempData["UsuarioTemp"]` execute o método a seguir :

```
TempData.Keep("UsuarioTemp")
TempData.Keep("nomeDaVariavel") //mantem o valor.

TempData.Remove("nomeDaVariavel") // remove o valor. se vc Não executar o   método TempData.Keep("nomeDaVariavel") após utilizar o seu conteúdo ele é removido automaticamente, por isso retorna null
```